# Row -1 or NSUIntegerMax Given by -[UITableViewDelegate tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, crash

Under what circumstances do UITableView give -1 or NSUIntegerMax for the row in -[UITableViewDelegate tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:]?

Below it is a crash log form an user.

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 9.2.1 (13D15)

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no object at index 18446744073709551615 in section at index 0'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181241900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001808aff80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreData                            0x0000000182cc50bc -[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:] + 456
3   My App                              0x000000010022c678 -[MyViewController tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:] (MyViewController.m:560)
4   UIKit                               0x0000000186145174 -[UITableView _titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:] + 160
5   UIKit                               0x00000001862756f4 -[UITableView _deleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:] + 116
6   UIKit                               0x0000000186275cf4 -[UITableView _swipeActionButtonsForRowAtIndexPath:] + 824
7   UIKit                               0x0000000186275998 -[UITableView _swipeActionButtons] + 92
8   UIKit                               0x0000000186144bd8 __32-[UITableViewCell _beginSwiping]_block_invoke + 120
9   UIKit                               0x0000000185f42964 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80
10  UIKit                               0x0000000186144b48 -[UITableViewCell _beginSwiping] + 96
11  UIKit                               0x0000000186272320 -[UITableViewWrapperView handleSwipeBeginning:] + 256
12  UIKit                               0x00000001864b4ea4 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 396
13  UIKit                               0x00000001860d85b8 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 172
14  UIKit                               0x0000000185f669b0 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 784
15  UIKit                               0x00000001864b63bc ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke904 + 72
16  UIKit                               0x0000000185f25b58 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 372
17  UIKit                               0x0000000185f228dc _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2404
18  UIKit                               0x0000000185f64820 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1132
19  UIKit                               0x0000000185f63e1c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 764
20  UIKit                               0x0000000185f344cc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 248
21  UIKit                               0x0000000185f32794 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 5528
22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001811f8efc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001811f8990 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001811f6690 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181125680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
26  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000182634088 GSEventRunModal + 180
27  UIKit                               0x0000000185f9cd90 UIApplicationMain + 204
28  My App                              0x00000001000a926c main (main.m:16)
29  ???                                 0x0000000180cc68b8 0x0 + 0
```

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyMessage *message = [self messageAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([message.senderUid isEqualToString:mUid])
        return NSLocalizedString(@"Delete", nil);
    else
        return NSLocalizedString(@"Hide", nil);
}

- (MyMessage *)messageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [mMessagesController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
}
```

Comment: did you check for the 'NSFetchedResultsController ' indexpath ?

Comment: What checking do you mean?

Comment: like this, did you check it get object in 'NSFetchedResultsController' it may crash from there also as shown in crash log: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896392/nsfetchedresultscontroller-crashes-on-objectatindexpath

Comment: The 2 in his problem was from his code directly. My problem was very different. As indicated by the stack trace, I did not input -1 directly. Some possibilities were reload or animation problems caused by or not by my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an iOS bug. Apple marked my bug as a duplicate of 23821434.

Answer (score 2):

`indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` are each a `NSUInteger` (unsigned integer), which means that it's strictly positive.  If you subtract and end up going negative, it jumps up to `NSUIntegerMax`.  This makes it necessary to be careful with arithmetic involving index paths.

When you do `row - 1` for `row` equal to zero, you will get `NSUIntegerMax`.

Comment: The value is given by iOS

Comment: Please show the line of code where iOS is giving that number.

Comment: That first line of code returns a string, so I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath gave me the NSUintegerMax row.

Comment: I you're saying that indexPath.row is equal to NSUIntegerMax.  If that's the case, have you tried logging it to see the actual value?

Comment: There was logging for the value. It was from a crash report. I cannot reproduce the problem. It was possible but very unlikely that NSFetched ResultController changed an valid value to -1. The major suspect should be UITbleView.

Comment: Do you have any code that directly calls tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: No. As indicated in the stack trace, the -1 was given by iOS

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is: under no circumstance. If you're cell would be out of bounds the crash would display on rendering time, not when accessing `[UITableViewDelegate tableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:]`

So the issue has to do with trying to retrieve an object from mMessagesController. Try using:

```
- (MyMessage *)messageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [[mMessagesController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
}
```

or

```
- (MyMessage *)messageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [mMessagesController objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

In Addition you could also filter the call to messageAtIndex to avoid going out of bounds.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row < [mMessagesController fetchedObjects].count && indexPath.row >= 0) {
        MyMessage *message = [self messageAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([message.senderUid isEqualToString:mUid])
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Delete", nil);
        else
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Hide", nil);
    } else {
        return NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil);
    }

}
```

Comment: Accessing the objects without checking will always crash if the index is -1. A check will prevent the crash but the invalid index indicated something went wrong. It might be corrupted UI or other things. The impact of the things went wrong was unknown. It is better to properly fix it or avoid the situation to appear.